# 403 Forbidden Error with Symfony website

Tags: php, symfony, server

I uploaded my Symfony project to the `public_html` directory of the server.

The website address is: http://sta275.mit13.csesalford.com/surveywebsite/

All file permissions are set to 644, I've tried different combinations however I keep getting this error:

> You don't have permission to access /surveywebsite/ on this server.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What server are you running?

Comment: Did you start the symfony server

Comment: Sorry, @Blueblazer172 Apache

Comment: @Blueblazer172 Why would i need to start the server if im not running it locally

Comment: Can you show me the apache.conf located in/etc/apache2/apache.conf

Comment: And the 000-default.conf

Comment: Are the `public_html` and `surveywebsite`  directories set to  0751 ? Also check your the apache error log to get more detailed information on the response

Comment: do you have a firewall enabled in the security.yml, there may be different settings for development and production.

Comment: Some formatting improvements.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Check your firewall settings to make sure that you don't have security enabled differently for production / development.

2.) Try running the application in development mode by going here: http://sta275.mit13.csesalford.com/surveywebsite/web/app_dev.php where you will see that you can access the app.

3.) Also try checking the log files located in /var/logs on the server. There may be clues in the there.

4.) It appears you can access the site in production mode by going to http://sta275.mit13.csesalford.com/surveywebsite/web/ also. This likely means there is a mis-configuration in your .htaccess file

Comment: I should add that you should not deploy your website with the app_dev.php, generally don't want the public to be able to access any parts of your development site